# DB update is not working in text input field when setting the value to 0 or " " using JS

Tags: jquery, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an update query in Laravel(v8) contains a checkbox together with text field.
Now I am trying to make the value empty or 0 if the default checked becomes unchecked.

Following is my jQuery code to make it unchecked and clear the values of text field and output scenarios.

**Case 1**

*Jquery*

```
$(document).on('click', '.surcharge_control', function(event) {
    $value = $(this).parent().next().val("0");
})
```

Output : new value 0 is not updated.

**Case 2**

*Jquery*

```
$(document).on('click', '.surcharge_control', function(event) {
    $value = $(this).parent().next().val("");
})
```

*Output* : DB not updated.

**Case 3**

*Jquery*

```
$(document).on('click', '.surcharge_control', function(event) {
    $value = $(this).parent().next().val("1");
})
```

*Output* : DB updated and value changed to 1

**Case 4**

*Jquery*

```
$(document).on('click', '.surcharge_control', function(event) {
    $value = $(this).parent().next().val("22");
})
```

*Output* : DB updated and value changed to 22.

Simply, DB is not updating when I set value to empty or 0. All other values are accepting.

DB column structure is given below.
[image: database columns]

Any idea why is this happening? Thank you.

Comment: Check if there is some check for 0 or empty string is in the code.

Comment: Your question largely depends on the validation on the server side. Please post the relevant controller and validation code as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, let me check the code..